# How to activate the splitter in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-editing

The [Notepad++ v7.6.2 release notes](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.6.2.html) reveal a new feature:

> 4. Add new feature: double click splitter resets panes to equal size.

How does one enable the splitter to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the file name in the tab bar and select Move/Clone to Other view.